# Power series of $\frac{1}{z^2 +4}$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Can anybody help me on this exercise?
I have to find the power series of the following function in zero.

$f(z) = (z^2 +4)^{-1}$

Can I use the Taylor formula?! Because then $f^{(n)}(0)$ will be zero for all $n>0$ but this does not look right to me :/

Would be nice if someone could give me a hint.

Comment: No, $f''(0)$ is not $0$. Please explain.

Comment: You are right. Stupid mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $z^2 \to 0$, one may use the standard geometric result,
$$
f(z)=\frac1{z^2+4}=\frac14\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{z^2}4}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{4^{n+1}}.
$$

Comment: I think there is an extra summation where there should not be one

Comment: @bburGsamohT Thank you very much, edited.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!

Comment: @nabla You are welcome.